# Working with models which don't have a single foreign key in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, relationships

I'm working on an application which has data imported from a foreign (and wholly unchangeable) source. I'll simplify some of the tables to explain the problem. Below are the tables with their primary keys.

```
invoices     (doc_number, date_printed, batch_number)
headers      (doc_number, date_printed, batch_number)
deliveries   (doc_number, date_printed, batch_number)
transactions (doc_number, date_printed, batch_number, line_number)
messages     (doc_number, date_printed, batch_number, line_number)
```

So you can see that Invoices, Headers and Deliveries have One-to-One relationships. Invoices-to-Transactions and Invoices-to-Messages are One-to-Many.

In importing these tables to my own database, I've changed the existing primary key to be a unique key and added an auto_incrementing field (`id`) on each table.

Now the problem is setting up the relationships in Cake, since it doesn't really handle composite keys at all. I've been able to get the One-to-One relationships working like this:

```
class Invoice extends AppModel {
    public $name = "Invoice"
         , $hasOne = array(
            "Header" => array(
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    "Invoice.doc_number = Header.doc_number",
                    "Invoice.date_printed = Header.date_printed",
                    "Invoice.batch_number = Header.batch_number"
                )
            )
         )
    ;
}
```

And this works, because the one-to-one relationships are queried in one go with a big LEFT JOIN. Trying the same method with a one-to-many relationship (eg, with Invoices and Transactions) dies, because Cake does two queries: the first to find all the matching Invoices, and then the second to find all the Transactions with a corresponding foreign key which matches the results from the first query: (here's the simplified query it's trying to run)

```
SELECT `Transaction`.* FROM `transactions` AS `Transaction`
WHERE `Invoice`.`doc_number` = `Transaction`.`doc_number`
AND `Invoice`.`date_printed` = `Transaction`.`date_printed`
AND `Invoice`.`batch_number` = `Transaction`.`batch_number`
```

You can see, it's not joining onto invoices so the query dies.

Any ideas about how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case scenario, you can use the finderQuery parameter of the [hasMany relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/view/82/hasMany).  It allows you to completely override the queries.

You might also be able to add a unique id field that combines the relevant data fields into one.  An UPDATE statement could fix existing data and a TRIGGER could be set up to update new records as they are added or changed, assuming that your database supports triggers.

**Edit:** With all of the other complexities, you might be better off skipping the hasMany relationship altogether and fetching the Transaction records in a separate find().  If you have to do it very many places you could always wrap it in a function in the Invoice model like this one:

```
<?php
class Invoice extends AppModel() {
    ...

    function getInvoice($conditions) {
        $invoice = $this->find('first', compact('conditions'));

        $conditions = array(
             'Transaction.doc_number' => $invoice['Invoice']['doc_number'],
             'Transaction.date_printed' => $invoice['Invoice']['date_printed'],
             'Transaction.batch_number' => $invoice['Invoice']['batch_number']);
        $invoice['transactions'] = $this->Transaction->find('all', compact('conditions'));

        return $invoice;
    }
}
?>
```

If you use a function like that in the model, don't forget that Invoice would need a defined relationship to Transaction, even if you don't use it directly, so that $this->Transaction is defined.

Also, if you prefer the data to be returned the way a hasMany relationship would be, you could always add a foreach loop to recombine them that way.

**Update**
There's also a [SimpleResults behavior in the Cake Bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/simpleresults-behavior-re-index-results-from-findall) that would allow easily returning those results from the other table in the format of a regular hasMany association.

Comment: so I tell Cake that it's a HABTM when it's really a "hasMany"? The really *really* awesome news (for me) about this data is that it's read-only in my application, so updates and triggers won't be a problem.

Comment: No, that should have been hasMany, and just finderQuery.  I misread something the first time through it.

Answer (score 0):

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find